# How to repeat a command on different values of the same variable using SPSS LOOP?

Tags: loops, syntax, spss

Probably an easy question:

I want to run this piece of syntax:

```
SUMMARIZE
  /TABLES=AGENCY
PIN
AGE
GENDER
DISABILITY
MAINSERVICE
MRESAGENCY
MRESSUPPORT
  /FORMAT=LIST NOCASENUM TOTAL
  /TITLE='Case Summaries'
  /MISSING=VARIABLE
  /CELLS=COUNT.
```

for 264 different agencies which are all values contained in the variable 'AGENCY'.

I want to create a different table for each agency outlining the above information for them.

I think I can do this using a DO REPEAT or LOOP on SPSS.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thank you :)

note: I have Google'd and read endless amounts on looping I am just a little unsure as to which method is what I am looking for

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`SPLIT FILE`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_sub/statistics_reference_project_ddita/spss/base/syn_split_file.html), which meets your needs

Comment: After you `sort cases by AGENCY.`  run  `split file by AGENCY.` and then run your analysis (any analysis) and you will get the results split by AGENCY as you wanted. (don't forget `split file off.` when you're done).